# How to change "Show [0] entries" when no matching records found

Tags: javascript, datatables

How can I change aLengthMenu to 0 and `Show [0] entries` in jQuery DataTables when search returns "No matching records found"?

See [this example](http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) and try to enter non-existing text in the search box.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 methods to do this.

1. By file

   `$('#myTable').DataTable({
       "language": {
         "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"
       }
   });`
2. Manual translation

   `$('#myTable').DataTable({
       "language": {
           "emptyTable":     "No hay datos disponibles",
           "info":           "Mostrando _START_ de _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ entradas",
           "infoEmpty":      "Mostrando 0 de 0 de un total de 0 entradas",
           "infoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ total entradas)",
           "infoPostFix":    "",
           "thousands":      ".",
           "lengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ entradas",
           "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
           "processing":     "Procesando...",
           "search":         "Buscar:",
           "zeroRecords":    "No se encontraron datos",
           "paginate": {
               "first":      "Primera",
               "last":       "ÚLtima",
               "next":       "Siguiente",
               "previous":   "Anterior"
           },
           "aria": {
               "sortAscending":  ": activate to sort column ascending",
               "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
           }
       }
   });`

You can see my post on [my blog](http://objetivobit.com/datatables-basic/) with basic usage and configurations. There are examples with jsFiddle

Comment: Thanks buddy for the effort, my question was changed, i meant - showing 0 in lengthmenu when there is no record found in table.

Comment: your link is expired

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`infoCallback`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/infoCallback) option to define a function that will be called when table information is about to be displayed.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "infoCallback": function(settings, start, end, max, total, pre){
     // If there are some records to display
     if(total > 0){
        return "Showing " + start + " to " + end + " of " + total + " entries" +
           ((total !== max) ? " (filtered from " + max + " total entries)" : "");

     // Otherwise, if no records to display
     } else {
        return "";
     }
  }        
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzjuxta9/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Am sorry, my question has been changed/modified, Actually my question is - showing 0 in drop down (aLengthMenu = 0) when there is no record found. Thanks